# maximum current drawn by an IC

Tags: power-supply, power, current, load

What is the maximum current drawn by an OP-Amp from the power supply (with load)? Is it with the range of Q current?

Comment: What does the spec. sheet for the **particular op-amp** you are thinking about say as we don't know which 'op-amp' you mean or what power supply you are referring to.

Comment: Read the datasheet! (duh)

Comment: @Manisha It depends on the op-amp and how its sourcing current and what the output driver stage is. An easy way would be to simulate the op-amp with spice if you want a ballpark power number. A way to estimate most amps is quiescent+load current.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My doubts are cleared :). Apology for not being clear with the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not very clear in your question. I assume you know what a datasheet is (since you talk about "Q current" - BTW, use the full term: *quiescent current*) and I guess you cannot make sense of the different parameters.

First of all let's consider a specific part, the jellybean LM358A dual opamp, and the relevant section of [its datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2904-n.pdf):

[image]

As you can see, it specifies that with no load (infinite load resistance), the part (i.e. the two opamps in the chip) will draw maximum 2mA from the supply. That's what you call quiescent current.

Of course, since any current provided to the load must come from the power supply, you must add that to the quiescent current whenever you have a load that draws significantly more current than the quiescent current.

Of course this brings us to the maximum current value that *a load can draw* from the output. Most non-specialized opamps have some kind of internal output current limiter, which is in the order of 20-60mA (very roughly). If your load attempts to draw more current, it will be automatically limited. Of course this is not good: although the opamp won't be usually damaged (but see note 5 below), the circuit won't work as intended if the current limiter kicks in.

See the relevant info in the datasheet:

[image]

[image]

And this is the internal circuit of a single section of that opamp that shows you more details:

[image]

Of course I simplified a bit the picture for the current path, since if the output sinks current instead of sourcing it, the path will go to ground internally, but you should get the point.

Comment: +1. I admire your patience of writing such a detailed answer (with beautiful extracts from the datasheets), for such a question.

Comment: @dim thanks! Sometimes I remember the questions I made to myself when I was lot younger, and had an hard time answering digging my nose deep in books with too theoretical models of things! :-)

Comment: Thank you Lorenzo for the detailed answer. This is what I was exactly looking for.:). Apologies for not being very clear with the question.

Comment: @Manisha You're welcome. Anyway remember to accept my answer as the correct one. Accepting (and upvoting, if you have the reputation score to do it) answers we think that are good is the way we show appreciation on this site and helps the best answers to shine and improve the overall quality of EE.SE.

Answer (score 2):

**Check the datasheet**

All opamps are different.  Look in the datasheet for the particular op-amp you have in mind, and it will tell you how much power it requires, and under what circumstances.